# How to write a downsampling function in Java

Tags: java, image-processing, signal-processing

I'm trying to write a filtering function for an image, but I can't seem to wrap my head around (or remember) how to transfer all that math theory into code.

Lets say I have the following function, where the ints inside the arrays are integers between `0` and `255` (pretty much grayscale pixels to keep it simple).

```
private int[][] resample(int[][] input, int oldWidth, int oldHeight,
        width, int height) 
{
    int[][] output = createArray(width, height);
        // Assume createArray creates an array with the given dimension

    for (int x = 0; x < width; ++x) {
        for (int y = 0; y < height; ++y) {
            output[x][y] = input[x][y];
            // right now the output will be "cropped"
            // instead of resampled
        }
    }

    return output;
}
```

Right now I'm stuck trying to figure out how to use filters. I've been trying wikipedia but I find the [articles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_scaling) [they](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Downsampled) [have](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nearest-neighbor_interpolation) there not particularly helpful. Can anyone clue me in on this or knows of any simple code sample?

Comment: Are you deliberately not using the Java APIs for image resizing? Is tis for an exercise? Homework?

Comment: I'm using Processing.org. My code is a bit more complicated than this and input is a repeating pattern (which I've written a function already to get pixels from). I eventually run into OutOfMemoryErrors when creating the output image and then resizing it with the Processing API. Since in the end I want it resized, I avoid unecessarily wasting heap space in Java by generating a resized version myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest approach would be nearest-neighbor downsampling, like this:

```
for (int x = 0; x < width; ++x) {
    for (int y = 0; y < height; ++y) {
        output[x][y] = input[x*width/oldWidth][y*height/oldHeight];
    }
}
```

But this doesn't give nice results, so you might need other approaches that use several input pixels and average them to get a more exact color for the original region.